# android: view cpu usage of processes

Tags: android, performance, process, task

Is there a process manager or task viewer for android that shows how much CPU percentage each process or even each thread in a process takes up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default this is not enabled. You just need to capture traces in those cases you would like to. Here you got a nice example: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html

Apart from that, Replica Island uses those methods if you would like to see a working example [www.code.google.com/p/replicaisland/](http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/)